# Numerically solving a SDE with Markovian switching?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, stochastic-calculus

Consider the reference paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0005109821004039

How would one go about numerically solving this system?

I tried for the one regime case:

```
b(* Recruitment rate *)= {0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6};
µ(* Natural mortality rate of S,E,I,Q,R *)= {0.05, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4};
µ1(* Natural mortality rate of S,E,I,Q,R *)= {0.09, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4};
\[Beta](* Transmission rate *)= {0.2, 1.3, 0.35, 0.8};
\[Lambda](* Recovered rate *)= {0.2857, 0.05, 0.2, 0.3};
\[Nu](* DID rate *)= {0.5, 0.05, 0.2, 0.3};
\[Tau](* Q to R *)= {0.08, 0.09, 0.7, 0.2};
\[Alpha]1(* Q to R *)= {0.01, 0.09, 0.7, 0.2};
\[Alpha]2(* Q to R *)= {0.01, 0.09, 0.7, 0.2};
\[Sigma](*Intensity of W1(t)*)= {0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.169};


tmax = 51; pWe1 = 
 RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, tmax}][[2, 1, 1]]; dW1 = 
 Interpolation[Table[{(j - 1), pWe1[[j]]}, {j, Length[pWe1]}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1];


eq1 = -s'[t] + (b0 - 
     beta s[t] i[t]/(1 + alpha1 s[t] + alpha2 i[t]) - (mu + nu) s[t] +
      nu s[t - tau] Exp[-mu tau]) - 
   sigma s[t] i[t]/(1 + alpha1 s[t] + alpha2 i[t]) dW1[t];
eq2 = -i'[
     t] + (beta s[
       t] i[t]/(1 + alpha1 s[t] + alpha2 i[t]) - (mu + mu1 + 
        lambda) i[t]) + 
   sigma s[t] i[t]/(1 + alpha1 s[t] + alpha2 i[t]) dW1[t];

ic1 = {s[t /; t <= 0] == 0.6, i[t /; t <= 0] == 0.3};

rul[j_] := {b0 -> b[[j]], beta -> \[Beta][[j]], 
   alpha1 -> \[Alpha]1[[j]], alpha2 -> \[Alpha]2[[j]], mu -> µ[[j]], 
   mu1 -> µ1[[j]], nu -> \[Nu][[j]], lambda -> \[Lambda][[j]], 
   tau -> \[Tau][[j]], sigma -> \[Sigma][[j]]};

eqn[j_] := {eq1, eq2} /. rul[j];

sol[j_] := NDSolve[{eqn[j] == {0, 0}, ic1}, {s, i}, {t, 0, tmax - 1}];

With[{sol = sol[1]},
 {Plot[Evaluate[s[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["Time(Days)", 20, Black], 
     Style["S(t)", 20, Black]}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black],
  Plot[Evaluate[i[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["Time(Days)", 20, Black], 
     Style["I(t)", 20, Black]}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black]}]
```

Comment: What about your question?

Comment: @AlexTrounev My question is how would we implement multiple regimes? And how would we plot the trajectory of the Markov chain?